# Truffle Javascript Testing VM Exception: Custom error (could not decode)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, javascript, custom-errors

I would like to know how to test custom error codes in my truffle javascript code. Originally I had string errors in my smart contract
and the javascript tests were passing.

Some time during development I began optimizing the code and changed the string to custom errors which I have trouble getting them to pass.

Here is the original solidity code with the string messages:

```
function stakeNFT(address nftContract, unint256 tokenId) {
    // some logic here
    require(IERC721(nftContract).ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "Not owner of nft 721");
    // some more logic

}
```

Below is my truffle test_contract.js script which was passing.

```js
it("should validate for 721", async function () {
    // code for account[0] to mint nft
    await expectRevert(
        registry.stakeNFT(nft721Contract, 1, {from: accounts[2], value: listingFee}),
        "Not owner of nft 721"
    );
}
```

This is part of the new smart contract optimized using custom errors:

```
// contract.sol
error NotOwnerOfNFT();

function someFunction(address nftContract, unint256 tokenId) {
    // some logic here
    if(IERC721(nftContract).ownerOf(tokenId) != msg.sender) revert NotOwnerOfNFT();

    // some more logic
}
```

When running the original javascript test against the new custom error solidity contract I get `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert --Reason given: Custom error (could not decode).` How do I modify my javascript test to properly validate custom errors? For some reason I cannot find much information on this.

Comment: After speaking with the Truffle team it seems like truffle debugger can decode but contract wrappers like this cannot.. TBD feature.